# How To get one list from a Generic list which contains difrent type of class, simply

Tags: c#, list, lambda, extension-methods, linq

I am testing a simple code block to be used in my project.Firsly I want to give example. Here is the class

```
class Processing
{
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public Car _car {get;set;}
    public double Kilometer { get; set; }
}



class Car
{
    public string LicansePlate { get; set; }
    public string Driver { get; set; }
    public double OdoMeter { get; set; }
}
```

Now. I have created List of Processing.This list contatin:

- **String** Region
- **Car** _car
- **double** Kilometer

I want to make list flatten using SelectMany() simply. Why I am using this way is SelectMany() will take "var" as referance in future.My Target outpur is like that :

```
Region   LicancePlate   Driver   Odometer  Kilometer
 ...        ...          ...     ...        ...
 ...        ...          ...     ...        ...
```

This code block is only test.Main Block is like that.

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
      List<Processing> proces;
       public MainWindow()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
         }

    private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        proces= new List<Processing>(){
                                            new Processing   {Region="Konya",Kilometer=96,_car= new Car(){LicansePlate="34 ABR 45", Driver="Hasan Doğan", OdoMeter=1322}},
                                            new Processing {Region="Karaman",Kilometer=233,_car=new Car{ LicansePlate="34 JT 9809" ,Driver="Ahmet Turgut",OdoMeter=1231}},
                                            new Processing { Region = "Ankara", Kilometer = 57, _car=new Car {LicansePlate = "34 JK 8547", Driver = "Tuncay Yıldız", OdoMeter = 472 }}
        };







        var kk = proces.SelectMany(b => b);


       dtgrid.ItemsSource = kk.ToList();
    }
```

**var kk = kullanımlar.SelectMany(b => b);** sentences give error.How to get all rows with sub field using SelectMany().Error is following : 
*cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.*

Comment: `kullanımlar` doesn't seem to be defined in the code you've presented. Please take some time to make the code snippet readable&runnable.

Comment: var doesn't mean the object doesn't need a type - only that the type is inferred

Comment: Sorry. I have just changed kullanımlar as proces. I will give anonymous list(var).So I must be able to make list flatten using SelectMany for all type of list.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want `Select` instead of `SelectMany`:

```
var kk = proces.Select(p => new {
    Region = p.Region, 
    LicencePlate = p.c.LicencePlate, 
    Driver = p.c.Driver, 
    Odometer = p.c.Odometer, 
    Kilometer = p.Kilometer
});
```

Comment: This way is good practice but not permanent solutions. I want Flatting processinc dynamilly.Because ı want to give referance var type. So that ı must be able to get Flated List , Whenever I give Diffrent type of list

Comment: You have to use
    dynamic myFlatList = new ExpandoObject();
put all property values into this dynamically from list
then push into grid. obaaaa ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "plane" list then you have to iterate properties.
you can do like this for example

write a recursive func that iterates proces[0] properties

```
     proces[0].getType().GetProperties()
```

could do getting properties...

when iteration gets a propertiy push in a Expando or something like then you there

you have a DYNAMIC FLAT list :)

In turkish, liste ne olursa olsun grid benzeri bir liste için propertiler içerisindeki classları da bir döngüyle alıp expando obje içine bas.. olay biter ;)

kolaylıklar diliyorum... Take it easy...